# jquery hover only to one div but defined for all divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs with same class

```
<a href="/News">
     <div class="menubutton" id="btnMenu" style="width: 80px;"><img src="/images/menu/Noticies.png" class="img-circle thumbnailMidSize"><span class="titleText" id="textmenu">Noticias</span></div>
</a>
<a href="/People">
     <div class="menubutton" id="btnMenu"><img src="/images/menu/Invitados.jpg" class="img-circle thumbnailMidSize"><span class="titleText" id="textmenu">Invitados</span></div>
</a>
```

I add an animation but only want to see the animation in the div selected not in both divs

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".menubutton").hover(function () {
        $(".menubutton").animate({ width: '310px' });

    });
    $(".menubutton").mouseleave(function () {
        $(".menubutton").animate({ width: '80px' });
    });
});
```

How can I change it to see the animation in only one div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are generalizing it. Use `this`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".menubutton").hover(function () {
        $(this).animate({ width: '310px' });

    });
    $(".menubutton").mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).animate({ width: '80px' });
    });
});
```

Also, there is a serious problem that you have `id="btnMenu"` repeated for two elements. The `id` values should alwys be unique.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **`this`** it refers to the object being hovered. Also **[`$( selector ).hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover1)** is shorthand for both  **[`$( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover1)**, so you can mouseleave callback as second parameter.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menubutton").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      width: '310px'
    });
  }, function() {
    $(this).animate({
      width: '80px'
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/News">
  <div class="menubutton" id="btnMenu" style="width: 80px;">
    <img src="/images/menu/Noticies.png" class="img-circle thumbnailMidSize"><span class="titleText" id="textmenu1">Noticias</span>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="/People">
  <div class="menubutton" id="btnMenu">
    <img src="/images/menu/Invitados.jpg" class="img-circle thumbnailMidSize"><span class="titleText" id="textmenu2">Invitados</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

**Note :**  In your markup the `id` attribute should be unique.

Answer (score 1):

You must also correct the id for the botton. you can't use the same id for two element.

correct in this way

```
<a href="/News">
   <div class="menubutton" id="btnMenu1" style="width: 80px;"><img src="/images/menu/Noticies.png" class="img-circle thumbnailMidSize"><span class="titleText" id="textmenu">Noticias</span></div>
</a>
<a href="/People">
 <div class="menubutton" id="btnMenu2"><img src="/images/menu/Invitados.jpg" class="img-circle thumbnailMidSize"><span class="titleText" id="textmenu">Invitados</span></div>
</a>
```

for the rest use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".menubutton").hover(function () {
      $(this).animate({ width: '310px' });

   });
   $(".menubutton").mouseleave(function () {
      $(this).animate({ width: '80px' });
   });
});
```

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer.

Comment: This could be the cause of the problem you downvote is noy justified my answer is correct ..and i posted the right code  remove your downvote

Comment: The jquery does not use the ID so while your *comment* is relavant it is not an answer.

Comment: The issue is the Jquery not the ID or HTML

Comment: I have update the answer now is complete. For correctnes you should remove the downvote

Answer (score 1):

You could use a reference to `this`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".menubutton").hover(function () {
        $this = $(this) // This is your reference to the object being hovered on
        $this.animate({ width: '310px' });
    });

    $(".menubutton").mouseleave(function () {
        $this = $(this) // Same here
        $this.animate({ width: '80px' });
    });
});
```